# How would Leibniz respond to this objection to his argument for God's existence?

Tags: theology, existence, leibniz, necessity

Leibniz argues for the existence of a necessary being using the Principle of Sufficient Reason (PSR).

1. Any contingent fact about the world must have an explanation. (Principle of sufficient reason)
2. The fact that there are contingent things can’t be explained by any contingent things.
3. The fact that there are contingent things must have an explanation. (1,2)
4. The fact that there are contingent things can’t be explained by any contingent things.
5. It is a contingent fact that there are contingent things.
   C. There is a necessary being. (5)

---

The objection to the argument goes something like this:

The necessary being (N) creates contingent things.

This fact is itself either necessary or contingent.

If it is a contingent fact that N creates contingent things, there is some reason for this fact, as stated by the PSR. However, N itself cannot explain the fact that N creates contingent things, as this is circular reasoning.

If it is a necessary fact that N creates contingent things, then contingent things are not contingent at all, but necessary. This contradicts a premise of the original argument.

So, if the fact that N creates contingent things is neither contingent nor necessary, it must be false. The argument must be wrong.

---

How do you think Leibniz would respond to this dilemma?

Comment: "If it is a necessary fact that N creates contingent things, then contingent things are not contingent at all, but necessary" is fallacious. Just because it is necessary that *a* contingent thing is created does not mean that *the* contingent thing created is necessary. There is no contradiction in N creating contingent things being necessary. There can be some things created in each possible world none of which is created in every possible world.

Comment: Welcome! You wrote: *"However, N itself cannot explain the fact that N creates contingent things, as this is circular reasoning."* I do not see how this is circular reasoning. N's existence and N's nature explain how N can and does create contingent things. For example if N is an all-powerful free agent, being all-powerful explains how it *can* create, and making a free choice explains why it *does* create a particular contingent world. You might then press me on what explains the fact that N has this particular nature, but this is a different issue than the creation of contingent *things*.